# Numeric Textbox: Display spaces

Tags: php, javascript, html, textbox

I have numeric textboxes in html/php/js where users will input numbers with 4 to 7 digits. However I would like the user to see spaces between every third digit.

For example,

```
        User inputs: 8000

        User sees: 8 000

        User inputs 9100045

        User sees: 9 100 045
```

How can I implement this so the input remains an int and does not get converted into a string with white space?

Thank you!

Comment: Use javascript/jQuery for when the user is inputting the data into the textbox, then strip all non-numeric values when storing it server-side.

Comment: Here is a jQuery plugin that will do the input masking: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ you will still need to convert the string to a number before you use it, but you should get the value without whitespace.

Comment: The `number_format` does the work.

Comment: You can't have a number with spaces so you will need to use a  **type="text"** input field and then make your server-side script take care of converting this into an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a standard textbox, this isn't possible.

Using javascript you could reformat the content after every key press adding spaces where necessary. However, as [@Jukka K. Korpela](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933530/numeric-textbox-display-spaces/10933559#comment14264343_10933559) has pointed out, this could become very confusing for the user. An alternative would be to make this change `onchange` so that the formatting only occurs when the textbox loses focus.

Then server side, remove all the spaces to return an integer.

Comment: Reformatting after every keypress would mean that after typing 1234, the user sees it converted to 1 234, and when he then types 5, the content gets converted to 12 345, etc. I'm not sure whether this is good usability. It could be really confusing. Reformatting after typing the entire number (onchange, onblur) would be less confusing but might not serve the intended purpose. It might be better to just let the user type 1 234 567 (and handle this properly both client-side and server-side).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Good point, I've edited the post. Personally I think any change made to the user input is going to confuse them rather than help.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in the PHP. For Eg., if the user enters the input here:

```
<input type="text" name="number" />
```

In PHP, get it as:

```
$number = intval(trim($_POST["number"])); // Get it as number
$number = number_format($number, 2, ' ', ' ');
// The value will be 5 00 000 for $number = 500000
$number = number_format($number);
// The value will be 6 000 000 for $number = 6000000
```

See [Number Format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for more information. Hope this helps! :)